# 'The memcache extension must be loaded for using this backend !'

Tags: apache, zend-framework, memcached

I'm trying to launch a local copy of a Zend-based app, and when I launch it, I get an Internal Server Error (code: 500).

According to the Apache log, `memcache` is not loaded:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Cache_Exception' with message 'The memcache extension must be loaded for using this backend !' in 
/Users/verse/Sites/tag/library/Zend/Cache.php:209

Stack trace:

#0 /Users/verse/Sites/tag/library/Zend/Cache/Backend/Memcached.php(123): >Zend_Cache::throwException('The memcache ex...')
#1 /Users/verse/Sites/tag/library/Zend/Cache.php(153): Zend_Cache_Backend_Memcached->__construct(Array)
#2 /Users/verse/Sites/tag/library/Zend/Cache.php(94): Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('Memcached', Array, >false, false)
#3 /Users/verse/Sites/tag/index.php(72): Zend_Cache::factory('Core', 'Memcached', Array, Array)
#4 {main}
  thrown in /Users/verse/Sites/tag/library/Zend/Cache.php on line 209
```

But I explicitly load it in my `php.ini`: `extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php55-memcache/2.2.7/memcache.so"`

Moreover, when I type `php -i | grep memcache` in the terminal, it says that `memcache` support is enabled:

>

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'memcache' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Warning: Module 'memcache' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Additional .ini files parsed => /usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d/ext-memcache.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d/ext-memcached.ini,
memcache
memcache support => enabled
memcache.allow_failover => 1 => 1
memcache.chunk_size => 8192 => 8192
memcache.default_port => 11211 => 11211
memcache.default_timeout_ms => 1000 => 1000
memcache.hash_function => crc32 => crc32
memcache.hash_strategy => standard => standard
memcache.max_failover_attempts => 20 => 20
memcached
memcached support => enabled
libmemcached version => 1.0.18
memcached.compression_factor => 1.3 => 1.3
memcached.compression_threshold => 2000 => 2000
memcached.compression_type => fastlz => fastlz
memcached.serializer => php => php
memcached.sess_binary => 0 => 0
memcached.sess_connect_timeout => 1000 => 1000
memcached.sess_consistent_hash => 0 => 0
memcached.sess_lock_wait => 150000 => 150000
memcached.sess_locking => 1 => 1
memcached.sess_number_of_replicas => 0 => 0
memcached.sess_prefix => memc.sess.key. => memc.sess.key.
memcached.sess_randomize_replica_read => 0 => 0
memcached.sess_remove_failed => 0 => 0
Registered save handlers => files user memcache memcached redis
```

However, when I create a dummy `index.php`, containing only `<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>`, and open it in the browser, the resulting page doesn't have any mentioning of `memcache`. And when I try to open my Zend app, it still throws the same error.

Is there a way to ensure that `memcache` actually loads on the server?

Comment: `phpinfo()` is the boss - if it says it isn't there, it isn't there. You may have only enabled it for CLI mode, or it may fail to load. Check your PHP error logs (be sure to enable `display_startup_errors`). More cannot be determined from the info shared now.

Comment: You probably have two different `php.ini` files; one for CLI, the other for web